# Unable to run the mvc5 project on IIS server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-deployment

I wanted to publish the my mvc5 application on **IIS server** and gone through with some references and finally I was able publish the project (through file system) from visual studio 2017.. After all my efforts I'm able to see the below screen when I browse the URL.

[image]

But it is not I expected, my actual running application in localhost is shown below.

[image]

I want to run the my actual project in IIS URL. What I can do to achieve this.

**EDIT:**

*For more info..*
Initially I got the issue which is shown in below image. For this fix, I've enabled the **Directory Browsing** in IIS server for my application. After enabling I face the above mentioned issue (shown in first image).

[image]

Any kind of suggestions are more helpful.

Comment: Sounds like your application pool is using wrong CLR related settings.

Comment: show us your IIS settings. You have to make it an actual application (or be at the root of a website) and ensure the .NET version is set correctly. What version of IIS is your server running?

Comment: IIS server version is 10.0.16299.15. How could I setup my site as an application in IIS manager.

Comment: tried reading the IIS docs?

Comment: Did you give some Alias name while creating the Application in IIS? then Add it and try it. For example : www.testproject.com/TEST

Comment: did you set the startup page/ default route?

Comment: Even after adding the application by giving alias I got the same page with file content. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Lex Li as you mentioned, the issue is caused the wrong CLR related settings for the application. And its my bad, I had used **DefaultAppPool**. Fixed the issue by giving the application pool as **.Net v4.5**. And also turned on the **.Net extensibility 4.7** feature (in *control panel -> programs and features -> Turn windows features on or off*) as shown in below.

[image]

Now the application is running as expected in IIS server.

[image]

Thank you for all your comments which helped me to dig more into this. :)